# SSIS Scripting Component using the CLR

Tags: .net, sql-server, sql-server-2005, ssis, clr

We are using SSIS with SQL Sever 2005 / VS 2008.

My colleague insists that we cannot use a scripting component inside the SSIS package because this will introduce executable code into the process then the CLR will have to be installed on the database server that is executing the job. Installing anything (if it doesn't exist already) on production machines would be problematic.

My question is, does adding the scripting component to a SSIS package cause it to have to call the CLR whereas SSIS did not have this dependency before?

Comment: @Siva, yes. In other words: if I do not use a Script Task or Script Component in my SSIS package will it run without the .net runtime framework installed, whereas if I do use scripting it will be required?

Comment: Can't you just check if the database server has .net already installed?  .Net 3.0 comes preinstalled on Windows Server 2008 and Windows Vista; .Net 3.5 comes preinstalled on Windows 7.

Comment: @BlueRaja It is windows 2003, so it is not pre installed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer the following MSDN link.

[**Hardware and Software Requirements for Installing SQL Server 2005**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143506%28SQL.90%29.aspx)

As per the documentation, `SQL Server 2005` installs `.NET Framework 2.0` on the machine (except for the `Express` edition, which requires manual install). SSIS packages require SSIS runtime engine. If you have that SSIS component installed, you don't need to install any other component to execute the packages even if they use `Script Task` or `Script Component`.

Following is the direct quote from **MSDN** and screenshot #**1** highlights the section in the MSDN.

**Quote from the MSDN:**

```
SQL Server Setup installs the following software components required by the
product:
 - Microsoft .NET Framework 2.0
 - Microsoft SQL Server Native Client
 - Microsoft SQL Server Setup support files
```

Hope that helps.

**Screenshot #1:**

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Siva's answer, if the colleague is really talking about enabling CLR in SQL Server instance (rather than installing .NET on the box) - he should not be worried, the Script component in SSIS has no dependency to SQL CLR.